# Cannot convert value of type 'collectionScannerViewController' to expected argument type 'AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate!'

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have some code for a barcode scanning application, everything is OK apart from the section below:

```
    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
    captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
    metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self,queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code]
```

I'm getting the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'collectionScannerViewController' to
>   expected argument type 'AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate!'

On the line

```
metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self,queue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

Doesn't seem to like me using self as the metadataobjectsdelegate, can anybody help me with why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I found it, didn't declare AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate with my view controller at the top.